# When creating a new VC++ console app error: cannot find source file stdio.h, tchar.h

Tags: visual-c++, console-application, header-files, stdio

I have just begun teaching myself VC++ using *Ivor Horton's Beginning Visual C++ 2010* and Visual Studio Professional 2010 . However, when I create a new VC++ console application through File -> New Project -> Win32 Console Application to create the default shell for a console application, I receive the following errors regarding the inclusion of default libraries in my stdafx.h file:

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory 
error: Cannot open include file:'tchar.h': No such file or directory
```

My stdfx.h file is as follows:

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
```

I can see that the files targeted by the include statements in stdafx.h are not pulled into the Header Files directory of my app, but I checked and I have VC++ 2010 x86 and VC++ x64  installed and assumed those files would be included with the install as the references are made with default generation of a new VC++ console application. Should I have to manually place these in the Header Files directory of each project? Shouldn't these be automatically pulled in?

UPDATE:
I looked in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include`
and I only see ammintrin.h, srv.h, wmiatlprov.h. Does this mean my Visual Studio install was potentially problematic? Can I just download the needed header files from somewhere and place them in this directory to correct the issue?

Comment: Several questions exactly like this, so far without a good diagnostic.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wmiatlprov.h

Comment: I'm really hoping there is a solution that doesn't require a complete uninstall then reinstall of Visual Studio, which is one of the common suggestions I have seen. Sigh.